# Does the order of the column name assignation in the join part have an impact on indexes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, index, join

Does the order of the column name assignation in the join part have an impact on indexes ?

For example, if I have an index on table X column Y, and I write:

```
SELECT * FROM B LEFT JOIN X ON X.Y = B.Y
```

Then the Y index from table X is used.  However, if I write the same query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM B LEFT JOIN X ON B.Y = X.Y
```

will the index still be used?

Comment: I don't see any reason for this to be closed. It's a clear, succinctly answerable question with broad real-world relevance: if the order of arguments to the `=` operator can affect query planning, then it's something worth tinkering with when trying to optimise a query, and if it can't, then it isn't. The selected close reason seems patently inapplicable here.

Comment: Also, the order of `AND` clauses in `ON` or `WHERE` does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no. Inner and Outer joins are not affected by the order tables and columns in the query. This can be confirmed by the result of `explain` as @ypercube mentioned.

However, if you join using "STRAIGHT_JOIN", then the order of the **tables** (not the columns) does matter.

Example:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM b STRAIGHT_JOIN x ON x.y = b.y;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref    | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | index | y             | y    | 5       | NULL   |   24 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | x     | ref   | y             | y    | 5       | so.b.y |    1 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT * FROM x STRAIGHT_JOIN b ON x.y = b.y;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref    | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | x     | index | y             | y    | 5       | NULL   |   24 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref   | y             | y    | 5       | so.x.y |    1 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using explain, as suggested by ypercube, the answer is no, the order does not matter. The index is used in both cases.